# I have followed all steps of Facebook audience network interstitial ads but still not show

Tags: android, facebook, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

I have followed all steps that is mention in Facebook audience network ads tutorial but still not showing interstitial ads "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID" as default key.

```java
InterstitialAd interstitial;
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MyStartActivity.this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");

interstitial.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
    @Override public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {}

    @Override public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {}

    @Override public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {}

    @Override public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {}

    @Override public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {}

    @Override public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {}
});
interstitial.loadAd();

if (interstitial.isAdLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
}
```

Comment: What is "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID"? Did you get one?

Comment: I didn't create my placement id, but this is for test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID" for InterstitialAd from Facebook audience network console.   after getting that you need to add test device to test ads.

AdSettings.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_HASH_ID");

Comment: Can we not test default "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID"? Before sometimes i was able to test and show interstitial ads without create live test id so.

Comment: no, I don't think Facebook audience network provides Test ids like Google AdMob does.

Comment: Can you please show on which URL this appears, and how it looks like (blur the private parts) .

Answer (score 1):

**Interstitial test ads  for facebook Audience network**
**variables**

```
com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd  interstitial;
    Ad adfacebook;
```

**In Oncreate Method**

```
AdSettings.setTestAdType(AdSettings.TestAdType.IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL);        AdSettings.getTestAdType();
AdSettings.setDebugBuild(true);
interstitial = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(StartActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_interstial));
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AbstractAdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                adfacebook = ad;
            }
        });
        interstitial.loadAd();
        interstitial.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad displayed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial dismissed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                // Ad error callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
                // Show the ad
              //  interstitial.loadAd();
               interstitial.show();
                adfacebook = ad;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
            }
        });
```

**In String.xml you put this**

```
 <string name="facebook_interstial">YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID</string>
```

**But when you put original Placement ID you Should Remove these line of Code**

```
AdSettings.setTestAdType(AdSettings.TestAdType.IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL);
    AdSettings.getTestAdType();
```

**Because this is only for test Ads**

Answer (score 0):

put  the  these  lines

```
AdSettings.setDebugBuild(true); // Remove this when put original ads
AdSettings.getTestAdType();   //Remove this when put original ads   this is only for test ads
```

after  audience.intialize   test ads  are  automatically shown